# Why I get the error "moment not defined" when I am trying to convert from datetime type into date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Basically I want to pull the data between Start Date and End Date from the system. So i have html page where i can put specific startdate and enddate and those dates are in date format. But system has date in datetime format. So i use below code to convert it into date format. But I receive the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined at API.html?StartDate=2018-12-01&EndDate=2018-12-31&submit=Submit:48

```
var i = 0;
while ((startdate >= (moment(res.responseJSON[i]['StartDate']).format('yyyy/mm/dd'))) 
        && (enddate <= (moment(res.responseJSON[i]['EndDate']).format('yyyy/mm/dd')))) 
{
  document.write(res.responseJSON[i]['StartDate']);
  document.write(res.responseJSON[i]['StartTime']);
  document.write(res.responseJSON[i]['EndDate']);
  document.write(res.responseJSON[i]['EndTime']);
  document.write(res.responseJSON[i]['EventID']);
  document.write(res.responseJSON[i]['Description']);
  document.write(res.responseJSON[i]['Category']);
  i++;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me what should i have to do?

Comment: Stupid questions first: did you import momentjs?

Comment: link moment.js file with your main html file where other script tags are added

Comment: You must include moment.js in your html page. [link](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It's not stupid, I mean, that's what the error is pointing at haha